# php debug problem in hellios

Tags: php

im trying to debug and im using eclipse hellios php version
and i get this message
"the debug session could not be started. please make sure that your debugger in properly configured as a php.ini directive"

what do i need to do
could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just confiure debugger. - [Xdebug](http://blog.thecodingmachine.com/content/setting-xdebug-debugging-environment-php-wamp-eclipse-pdt) or [Zend Debugger](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/php/987-developing-with-php-and-eclipse-helios.html?start=2)